# Windows 10 file explorer randomly corrupted since update

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mouse

Yesterday suddenly my windows file explorer looked strange (see screenshot) and even the behaviour of my mouse changed, where I always had to double click to open something, now it opens up with one click, i can't even change it back, and files & folders are now underlined if mouse hovers, I also noticed that I cannot press ALT+RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON, the context menu disappears in milliseconds.

All this happened after a update 2 days ago.
I searched for a solution but didn't found no similar problems that could help me to fix this issue.

One possible solution (that didn't solve it) i tried was this, running from the command line:

> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
>
> sfc /scannow

The refresh button and history button looks strange/wrong (see red circle):

[image]

Files and folder are now underlined (see red circle):

[image]

Changing to single click to open items is not possible:

[image]

UPDATE:

I checked what happend during the last update and i found out that Microsoft Office 365 Business was updated/installed, maybe this issue is related to MS Office.

The last update in the update history:

"Funktionsupdate für Windows 10, Version 1709"
(Translation: Featureupdate, Version 1709)

Answer (score 0):

Normally no matter which feature update or Microsoft office product update will not bring such symptoms to the system.
If the issue has not been resolved, I would recommend to perform a full scan with antivirus software such as malware, virus or Windows Defender software to make sure you really have a safe environment.
Another doubt is to make sure if it was caused by system files corruption.
If you suspect it was caused by an upgrade, a startup repair is useful to fix it.
If you suspect it caused by a specify application, try to repair through control panel -> program and feature might be useful for you.